# Java 8 lambda list inside list filter

Tags: java, lambda

Sample JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "333",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "id": "222",
        "status": "Inactive"
      },
      {
        "id": "111",
        "status": "Active"
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "6",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "status": "Inactive"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to retrieve list of objects that have at least one active product.

Below code returns list of products but I want a list of `ProdcutResponse`. Any way to do this?

```
 response.stream()
 .map(ProductResponse::getProducts)
 .filter(s -> "Active".equals(s.getType()))
 .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you didn't show much code, this will be a shot in the dark.  My main suggestion would be to not map the `Stream<ProductResponse>` to a `Stream<List<Product>>` before collecting it to a list:

```
response.stream()
        .filter(pr -> pr.getProducts().stream().anyMatch(s -> "Active".equals(s.getType())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can change `anyMatch` to `allMatch` if you want the `List<ProductResponse>` to contain **only**`Product`s with active types (whatever that means).

Comment: @Forhad The time complexity is `O(n^2)`. Some pre-computation would be required to optimize it.